# GROUP BY with JOIN not giving correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How can I find the number of persons from each country

**Person table**

> country_id, fName, lName

**Countries table**

> country_id, country_name

I can find the number of persons from each country with their country IDs, using the below SQL statement

```
select   
 p.country_id, COUNT(p.country_id) as [Count] 
from 
 persons p
GROUP BY
 p.country_id
```

But what if I want to fetch country_name instead of country_id?
I tried this so far but it does not work as expected so I am missing something here.

```
select   
    c.country_name, COUNT(p.country_id) as [Count] 
from 
    persons p INNER JOIN countries c ON p.country_id = c.country_id  
GROUP BY
    p.country_id
```

SQL Server 2000

Comment: "it does not work as expected": why not?

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` the columns in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT c.country_name, COUNT(p.country_id) as [Count] 
FROM persons p INNER JOIN
     countries c
     ON p.country_id = c.country_id  
GROUP BY c.country_name;
```

Notes:

- Under some circumstances, you would want to include both the id and the name in the `GROUP BY` -- this would happen if two countries had the same name.
- You can use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(p.country_id)`.  There is no problem counting *rows* instead of `NULL`-values.

If you wanted all countries, even those without people, then you would use an outer `JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.country_name, COUNT(p.country_id) as [Count] 
FROM countries c LEFT JOIN
     persons p
     ON p.country_id = c.country_id  
GROUP BY c.country_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the column_name which is mentioned in `select` .

```
select   
    c.country_name, COUNT(p.country_id) as [Count] 
from 
    persons p INNER JOIN countries c ON p.country_id = c.country_id  
GROUP BY
    c.country_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use group by c.country_name .. the column you have in select and you use for refer the group by

```
select    c.country_name, COUNT(p.country_id) as [Count] 
from  persons p INNER JOIN countries c ON p.country_id = c.country_id  
GROUP BY  c.country_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement is correct. There was some data corruption in the database due to which the results were not returned correctly.